# Error en Android Studio al registrar usuarios

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mysqli, jsonobject

Trabajando en una aplicación de Android Studio quiero hacer un registro a una base de datos.
Quiero que la informacion se registre en 2 tablas diferentes **Alumno** y **Maestra**, hago el registro con JSONObject y PHP con **mysqli**.

Al ejecutar mi apicacion la informacion si se registra en Maestra, pero no se registra en Alumno.
use `Log.i("tagconvertstr", "["+response+"]");` para ver si habia algun error y salieron estas advertencias y errores:

```
Warning:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro.php on line 39

Warning:  mysqli_stmt_execute() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro.php on line 40
{"success":true}
Notice:  Undefined variable: mysqli in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro.php on line 47

Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to a member function close() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro.php:47
Stack trace:

  thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro.php on line 47
```

El codigo para registrar en android es:

```
public RegisterRequest(String Nombre, String ApellidoP, String ApellidoM,String Boleta, String psw, int Area, int LunesI, int LunesF, int SabadoI, int SabadoF, Response.Listener<String>listener)
{
    super(Method.POST,REGISTER_REQUEST_URL,listener,null);
    params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("Nombre",Nombre);
    params.put("ApellidoP",ApellidoP);
    params.put("ApellidoM",ApellidoM);
    params.put("Boleta",Boleta);
    params.put("psw",psw);
    params.put("Area",Area+"");
    params.put("LunesI",LunesI+"");
    params.put("LunesF",LunesF+"");
    params.put("SabadoI",SabadoI+"");
    params.put("SabadoF",SabadoF+"");
}
@Override
public Map<String, String> getParams(){return params;}
```

Y el php es :

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "proyecto");

$Area = $_POST["Area"]; //int
$Boleta = $_POST["Boleta"]; //string
$psw = $_POST["psw"]; //string
$Nombre = $_POST["Nombre"]; //string
$ApellidoP = $_POST["ApellidoP"]; //string
$ApellidoM = $_POST["ApellidoM"]; //string
$LunesI = $_POST["LunesI"]; //int
$LunesF = $_POST["LunesF"]; //int
$SabadoI = $_POST["SabadoI"]; //int
$SabadoF = $_POST["SabadoF"]; //int

$Turno = "m";
$Grupo = '6IM14';
$Carrera = 1;
$Direccion = '@@';
$Telefono = "222";
$Semestre = 6;
$vigencia = '12-may-2020';
$horas = 0;
$HorasE = 0;
$ES = 1;
$Num_Maestro = "123";

$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO Alumno (Nombre, ApellidoP, ApellidoM, Boleta, Turno, Grupo, Carrera, horas, HorasE, ES, psw, Area, Num_Maestro, Direccion, Telefono, Semestre, vigencia, LunesI, LunesF, SabadoI, SabadoF) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "ssssssiiiisisssisiiii", $Nombre, $ApellidoP, $ApellidoM, $Boleta, $Turno, $Grupo, $Carrera, $horas, $HorasE, $ES, $psw, $Area, $Num_Maestro, $Direccion, $Telefono, $Semestre, $vigencia, $LunesI, $LunesF, $SabadoI, $SabadoF);
mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

$response = array();
$response["success"] = true;

echo json_encode($response);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Warning:  mysqli_stmt_bind_param() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Registro.php on line 39
```

El error te está indicando, que el primer parámetro de la función($statement), es un boolean, por lo que probablemente tengas problemas con tu conexión o con tu sentencia. En primer lugar, prueba si tienes la conexión establecida if($con) y si no es así, muestra por pantalla qué ha ocurrido.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "proyecto");

if ($con){
    ...tu código...
}else{
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    $response["success"] = false; 
}
echo json_enconde($response);
```

Del mismo modo que pruebas la conexión, prueba que tu "statement" sea correcto.

```
$statement = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO Alumno (Nombre, ApellidoP, ApellidoM, Boleta, Turno, Grupo, Carrera, horas, HorasE, ES, psw, Area, Num_Maestro, Direccion, Telefono, Semestre, vigencia, LunesI, LunesF, SabadoI, SabadoF) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)

if ($statement){
    ...tu código...
}else{
    echo mysqli_stmt_error($statement);   
    $response["success"] = false;
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Ya hice las modificaciones que me dijiste, pero ahora el problema es que no manda error pero no registra nada en alumno, al correr un `SELECT * FROM Alumno` no me regresa nada. Sabes porque puede ser?

Comment: Teniendo las comprobaciones, ¿no obtienes ningún mensaje de error y la respuesta es {"success":true} ? Puede ser que no te de directamente ningún error, porque estás entrando en uno de los else y por tanto ni siquiera se está haciendo la inserción.

Comment: Segun la consola si sale un `{"success": true}` pero al revisar la base de datos no se ha registrado